# Fetch all the values of on attribute/field from an array of objects

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using Nodejs and MongoDB. This is my data:

```
[{Id:1234
Name:someone,
Email: someone@gmail.com},
{Id:4321
Name:john,
Email: john@gmail.com},
{Id:6789
Name:sarah,
Email: sarah@gmail.com}]
```

I want to get all the values of the name field and send it as a response to the frontend. I tried using find.project and some other methods but it keeps on returning a null array.

I'm new at Mongoose and Nodejs so that's why I'm not sure how this is supposed to be done.

Comment: Atleast work on the problem and try to get it solved before posting here....people help you out by providing correct solutions but u dont try those and get it solved by yourself with a similar solution and after that u edit the question with solved update. Dont post questions if u have not applied any effort solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Model.find({}, {name: 1, _id: 0}, (error, data) => {
   if (!error) {
     // send data in your response.
   }
 });
```

Note: Here Model is your mongoose db model.

Comment: Thanks @Baptiste Wicht

Answer (score 0):

Query the collection using the following code inside the GET route,

```
Collection.find({})
       .then(users=>{      // users variable stores all records fetched from the database 
           res.render("usersHTML",{users});    // "usersHTML" is the ejs file
       })                                      // users data are passed to the ejs file 
       .catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
```

Now as the users records are passed to the frontend just use a loop to traverse  the users and get the names of each record using `users[i].name`.

Comment: I want to filter the data at the server/backend not the frontend.

Comment: ok so create an array. Then traverse the "users" using for loop and insert all names into the created array and pass the array to front end simple.

Comment: can I use arr.filter over here? I know we can use it but idk how

Comment: u want all the values of names so why using filter. You can do using a normal for loop so why to use inbuilt function.